# Cannot tail .log files inside docker container

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that runs multiple python scripts with pm2, each one of them has its own .log file and I want to tail them separately in order to debug them easily. The problem is when I run `docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/sh` and `tail -f scriptFile.log` inside the directory where the file is located only shows the first lines and it freezes until hit `ctl + c`. The image I'm using is **nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.9-nodejs16-alpine** from [enter link description here](https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs)

Also tried `docker logs tail -f container /app/logfile.log`

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.9-nodejs16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Installing pm2
RUN npm install pm2 -g

# Create prod env variable
ENV PROD=true

COPY . .
# Installing lxml
RUN apk add --update --no-cache g++ gcc libxslt-dev
# Installing requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js"]
```

Comment: when you do `ls -lh` what is the file size?
usually this happens when you have a empty file

also, you try to add text yourself, and check if you see it with tail
`echo 'test' > scriptFile.log`

Comment: @flaxon it´s not empty the size just shows 6856 but not a letter I think these are image stuff

Comment: does it work with just 10 lines? `tail -n 10` does it work with `cat`

Comment: @flaxon works with ```tail -n 10``` and also ```cat``` but can't follow it

Comment: i think its just to big, try with both like this `tail -n 10 -f ...`

Comment: Can you run multiple containers, one to a process, without pm2; send logs directly to stdout and not log files, and then use `docker logs` to look at individual containers'/processes' log output?